# How do I use selenium to connect to an existing FireFox instance through debugger port?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to startup Firefox and geckodriver seperately, but it seems that selenium didn't export an interface for running a geckodriver which preprares for connect to an exisiting FireFox instance.

For chromium, I can use the following code to finish this task:

```
chromium = subprocess.Popen(
            [self.chromium_path, "--headless", "--no-sandbox",
             "--remote-debugging-port=" + port])
ops = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        ops.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:" + port
browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(self.chrome_driver_path, options=ops)
```

How do I run FireFox in this way?

Answer (score 0):

First, start Firefox in remote controllable state:

1. Close all instances of Firefox
2. Start Firefox with the poorly documented --marionette command line switch:

   "c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" --marionette

Firefox will start, and apart from the little robot icon, and the quite annoying pink/gray stripes over the address bar, it will operate normally.

Then [download the latest version of GeckoDriver from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Copy it into the same directory where you have firefox.exe, (c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ on Windows). After all, it is part of Firefox, and should have been distributed with Firefox.

Then, in Selenium Java, open FirefoxDriver like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService;

public final class Browser {
    private Browser() {
    }

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static WebDriver open() throws IOException {
        if (driver == null) {
            List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
            args.add("--port=43068");
            args.add("--allow-origins");
            args.add("http://127.0.0.1:45015");
            args.add("http://localhost:45015");
            args.add("http://[::1]:45015");
            args.add("--marionette-port=2828");
            args.add("--connect-existing");
            var env = new HashMap<String, String>();
            var service = new GeckoDriverService(
                new File("c:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe"),
                43068,
                Duration.ofSeconds(20),
                args,
                env
            );
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        }
        return driver;
    }
    ...
```

Unfortunately you cannot use GeckoDriverService.Builder, because createArgs() is hard-coded there, and it is unable to insert the most important "--connect-existing" argument into the argument list.

I am sorry for the hard-coded magic port numbers in the example. I have a properly written and more comprehensive answer on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/pintergabor/selenium-firefox-demo) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/pinter-gabor-at/selenium-firefox-demo).